# Cancel Google Play subscription with Billing API?

Tags: android, google-play-services, play-billing-library

Is there a way to cancel a subscription with the Google Play Billing API, specificaly using BillingClient, or I have to do it through the Google Play Developer API? Seems counterintuitive that you can't unsubscribe the same way you subscribed, but I can't find a way to do it. Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BillingClient` doesn't support cancellation (not too sure what Google's reasoning was on that one).

You would have to use [Purchases.subscriptions:cancel](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel). I'm not certain, but I believe only the app publisher can call that API; IOW, users can't call it on their own behalf. Clearly there must be an API that works off a user's Google Account credentials, but I don't know what it is.

An email sent by the Google Play Team on 13 Jun 2018 recommended that users be directed to manage their subscriptions in one of the following ways:

> On Android, open the Google Play Store, then tap Menu > Subscriptions.
>
> On a computer, go to play.google.com, then in the left menu click My subscriptions.
>
> On either Android or a computer, use the URL http://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions to open the user's list of subscriptions.
>
> For active subscriptions, use the deep-link http://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?package=samplePackage&sku=sampleSKU with your package and SKU name to directly open the page to manage the user's specific subscription. Learn more about the manage subscription deep-link by checking out our documentation for [subscription-specific features](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#deep-links-manage-subs).

Comment: Well that sucks...thanks for answering though. So there is no way to get feedback when user unsubscribes from Play Store other than queryng the purchase details each time it might have happened?

Comment: Hmm that's a good question. There is a "cancellations report" on Google Play, and you can, of course, check your Google Play "orders" list periodically... But I think what Google expects developers to do is poll `queryPurchases()` from within the app. Once a subscription gets cancelled, `Purchase.isAutoRenewing()` should start returning false. After all, doesn't it make sense that the user's Google Play service should be one of the first things to learn about the cancellation?

Comment: I'll just have to think of something, thanks for the input. Sorry to bother you with one more question, but is there a way to test subscriptions without spending real money? The documentation says that static (fake) skus don't work only for one time purchases, and not subscriptions....

Comment: I've never found a way to do it without real money. You can just refund it to yourself, though; Google won't take their piece of the pie if you refund it.